# ConjureHTTPError -- How to resolve?

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api

A 404 Client Error: Not Found error occured calling https://core.skywise.com/codex-hub/api/v1/computation/output. ErrorName: CodexHub:SeriesNotFound. Please review and contact support if the problem persists.

I get the following error when working with Palantir Foundry. Anyone has any idea how to resolve this? Many thanks.

Think it's a backend issue, Full error message:

Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://core.skywise.com/codex-hub/api/v1/computation/output

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/vector_spark_module-5.594.0-py3.6.egg/vector/execution/execution.py", line 344, in _evaluate
return eval(compile(code, filename, 'eval'), namespace)  # pylint: disable=eval-used
File "hydraulic_transformation_temperature", line 1, in 
File "hydraulic_transformation_temperature", line 33, in hydraulic_transformation_temperature
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/core/collection.py", line 431, in to_dataframe
return fts.session.createDataFrame(rdd, self._spark_data_type(), verifySchema=False)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/core/collection.py", line 641, in _spark_data_type
for column, column_type in zip(self.columns(), self.types())])
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/core/collection.py", line 361, in types
child_types = self._node_schema()[1]
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/core/collection.py", line 626, in _node_schema
unique_columns_and_types = [
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/core/collection.py", line 631, in 
for column, column_type in zip(node.columns(), node.types())
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/nodes/node.py", line 173, in types
return self._single_child_getattr('types')()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/nodes/node.py", line 173, in types
return self._single_child_getattr('types')()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/nodes/transformations.py", line 495, in types
return _types(self)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/nodes/transformations.py", line 393, in _types
if is_enum_node(node):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/_utils/codex_outputs.py", line 6, in is_enum_node
node_output = node.output_type()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/nodes/node.py", line 133, in output_type
self._output_type = foundryts.FoundryTS()._output_type(self)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/foundryts/core/_foundryts.py", line 241, in _output_type
return self.hub.compute_output(
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/codex_hub_api/_impl.py", line 14744, in compute_output
_response = self._request( # type: ignore
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/conjure_python_client/_http/requests_client.py", line 106, in _request
raise_from(ConjureHTTPError(e), e)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/future/utils/**init**.py", line 406, in raise_from
exec(execstr, myglobals, mylocals)
File "", line 1, in 
conjure_python_client._http.requests_client.ConjureHTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://core.skywise.com/codex-hub/api/v1/computation/output. ErrorCode: 'NOT_FOUND'. ErrorName: 'CodexHub:SeriesNotFound'. ErrorInstanceId: '65efb952-229c-4012-8091-4c1731aa240e'. TraceId: 'f6edb280f9bafb00'. Parameters: {'seriesIds': '[(ac:a350)-(reg:9V-SHN)-(msn:385)-(acu:RSVTMPG:1)-(ch:96)]'}

Answer (score 0):

`CodexHub:SeriesNotFound` likely means that the timeseries serie ID you are querying does not exist.

I don't have enough details in your post to help more, as I guess you call it from code repository ? So you might have a way to figure out which serie id is wrong ?